# Netlink notification for iptable modification are not received to application

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, iptables, netlink

I wrote a program to listen to iptables modification through netlink sockets, for this I used `NETLINK_AUDIT` family, when I execute the program and modify the iptables rule, program doesn't receive any message from kernel and it will be in blocking mode only. Could you help me to find what is wrong in this program or what else I need to do to receive iptables notification.

```
#include "libaudit.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        int rc;
        struct audit_message rep;
        int fd;
        struct sockaddr_nl sa;

        memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
        sa.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
        sa.nl_groups = 0; 

        fd = audit_open();

        bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &sa, sizeof(sa));

        rc = audit_get_reply(fd, &rep, GET_REPLY_BLOCKING, 0);
        if(rc < 0)
        {
                printf("Error");
        }
        else
        {       
                printf("msg received %d \n",rep.nlh.nlmsg_type );
                break;
        }       


        audit_close(fd);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you running this program as a root / privileged user ?

Comment: Yes,running as a root user.

Comment: do you have auditd running ?

Comment: Yes.                                                            
ps -eaf | grep -i auditd
root       499     2  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root       926     1  0 Nov16 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/auditd -n

Comment: can you check return value of bind and if it is less than zero use perror or check errno ?

Comment: i checked earlier with prints ,bind is returning success ,it gets stuck in receive blocking call .

Comment: you mean "audit_get_reply" this is blocking call right ?

Comment: check validity of fd. need to check return value whenever it expects error. let me know. I think less chance of it being invalid as bind is succeeding. please let me know is not -1.

Comment: Hi,its +ve value ,i checked it.

Answer (score 0):

try this flag

https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/lib/libaudit.c#L383

from libaudit source code

```
rc = audit_get_reply(fd, &rep, GET_REPLY_NONBLOCKING,0);
```

Comment: I have tried this as well before ,since it's non blocking call,it will come out without waiting there(used the polling as well before thi call) but not received any data

Comment: Is there any other way as well to receive the  iptable change notification ?

Comment: maybe you have to configure audit with `auditctl` ? can you consult man page and try configuring  it ?

Comment: from your observation it is clear that there is less probablity of this code having problem. as it may have given some error. so I feel is audit is not configured to listem to netlink related or for that matter any call by default. I suggest you to go through this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sec-defining_audit_rules_and_controls specifically example 7.2 and try simmilar thing with given example try it works and then do same/ related  for netlink

Comment: I tried configuring those setting earlier directly using auditctl command & can see the modifcation with "ausearch -k iptablesChange" command output..this time i configured more rules in /etc/audit/audit.rules file but still issue persist.

Comment: have you tried system calls and checked with your program ? just to be sure there is no problem in program and audit system. let me know if you see anything in your program when you try system call.

Comment: i tried with system call in that program ,it worked.                                                    
char command[50];
 
   strcpy( command, "ls -l" );
   system(command);

Comment: this means your program and libaudit is working so now just need to figure out right configuration for  iptable notifications. let me check if i find any.